# Marklogic TDE views and join

Tags: sql, marklogic, marklogic-9

How do Marklogic TDE view perform joins between two views

I have created two simple TDE Templates with one join column. I can perform a `select` query with join and it works fine. My question is what kind of join is actually being done in the MarkLogic database? Is it doing full document scans that will become bottleneck once volume of data grows?

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace tde = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde"  at "/MarkLogic/tde.xqy";

let $emp1 := <employee><id>100</id><name>john</name><dept>10</dept></employee>
let $emp2 := <employee><id>200</id><name>mary</name><dept>10</dept></employee>
let $dept1 := <dept><id>10</id><name>accounting</name></dept>
let $dept2 := <dept><id>20</id><name>hr</name></dept>
let $emp-table := <template xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde">
  <context>/employee</context>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <schema-name>models</schema-name>
      <view-name>employees</view-name>
      <columns>
        <column>
          <name>id</name>
          <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
          <val>id</val>
        </column>
        <column>
          <name>name</name>
          <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
          <val>name</val>
        </column>
        <column>
          <name>dept</name>
          <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
          <val>dept</val>
        </column>
      </columns>
    </row>
  </rows>
</template>      
let $dept-table := <template xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde">
  <context>/dept</context>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <schema-name>models</schema-name>
      <view-name>depts</view-name>
      <columns>
        <column>
          <name>id</name>
          <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
          <val>id</val>
        </column>
        <column>
          <name>name</name>
          <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
          <val>name</val>
        </column>
      </columns>
    </row>
  </rows>
</template>              
return (
  xdmp:document-insert('/employees/100.xml', $emp1),
  xdmp:document-insert('/employees/200.xml', $emp2),
  xdmp:document-insert('/depts/10.xml', $dept1),
  xdmp:document-insert('/depts/20.xml', $dept2),
  tde:template-insert('/templates/emp.xml', $emp-table),
  tde:template-insert('/templates/dept.xml', $dept-table)
)
```

Then

`select employees.name, depts.name from employees, depts where employees.dept = depts.id`

The select works great.

My question is what's happening under the hoods. Is it doing equivalent of a HashJoin or full table scan? What are implications if number of documents go up to millions and billions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [xdmp:sql-plan](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:sql-plan) to better understand how your query gets executed.

A similar query to yours on my machine reveals that a `bloom-join` is used. This might differ on your machine depending on your query. But you should be able to find out what is going on having the sql plan.

```
<plan:plan xmlns:plan="http://marklogic.com/plan">
  <plan:select>
    <plan:project order="">
      <plan:vars>...</plan:vars>
      <plan:expr>
        <plan:join join-type="bloom-join" order="40[NULLS_IRRELEVANT]">
          <plan:join-info>
            <plan:hash left="4" right="1" operator="="></plan:hash>
            <plan:filters>...</plan:filters>
          </plan:join-info>
          <plan:elems>...</plan:elems>
          <plan:filters>..</plan:filters>
        </plan:join>
      </plan:expr>
    </plan:project>
  </plan:select>
</plan:plan>
```

Comment: One footnote on this sensible answer:  the join, lexicon, and triple accessors always read indexes and never scan documents.